# nginx redirect from web root to a and if 404 then try b

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I am trying to amend my nginx config to redirect from the web root ("/") to **/dir-a** and then if this returns a 404 redirect to **/dir-b**. I'm not entirely sure how or if this is possible though.

This is what I have so far...

```
    location = / {
            rewrite "/" /dir-a permanent;
    }
```

But this returns the 404 page so I'm not sure where to go from here. I need it to try dir-b instead.

Comment: There are some tricks you can perform with an `error_page 404`. [See the documentation here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page).